Reprojecting Datasets to S2 (Cube Projection)
I am trying to reproject GeoTIFF datasets (of various SRS) to the S2 PCS using GDAL.
For demonstration I am using a downscaled GEBCO dataset.
I would like to reproject my source dataset to the overlapping S2 faces.
So for global datasets I would like to have 6 output datasets of similar size.
For local datasets I would like to have only a couple of datasets, that cover the specific area.
My GDAL commands look something like this:
gdalwarp gebco_large.tif s2.tif -t_srs "+proj=s2 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +UVtoST=quadratic"

This results in an output image, where the georeferenced corner coordinates are outside of the valid st range.
For example:
Upper Left  (  -3.4121903,   4.4121903) ( 45d 0' 0.00"W,  1d35'29.04"N)
Lower Left  (  -3.4121903,  -3.4127405) ( 45d 0'26.05"E,  1d35'28.31"N)
Upper Right (   4.4127405,   4.4121903) (135d 0'26.05"W,  1d35'28.31"N)
Lower Right (   4.4127405,  -3.4127405) (135d 0' 0.00"E,  1d35'27.59"N)
Center      (   0.5002751,   0.4997249) (135d 0' 0.00"E, 89d58'13.70"N)

Is there a way I can clamp these to [0, 1], so that the output is a correct s2 dataset?
Also projecting to sides lat0_0=0 lat0_0=0 does not work at all.
Source dataset:

S2 dataset incorrect:

S2 dataset correct:

